# WPF Hide MenuItem Key Binding

Tags: wpf

I have a File menu with an Open item bound to the ApplicationCommands.Open command.  By default this is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

In addition, I have a Recent Items submenu where I programmatically add recently opened files, and also bind these to the ApplicationCommands.Open command.

This seems like the semantically correct thing to do since in all instances I'm trying to Open a new file.

However, the Recent Items menu now shows the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> keybinding beside each item, and I would like to hide this binding in the UI. Is there a way to accomplish this? The best option I've come across is to create a custom command, which seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `InputGestureText=" "` on the `MenuItem`.  That's a single space, not an empty string.

Setting an empty string won't work *most* of the time because `MenuItem.CoerceInputGestureText` will treat this as an 'unset' value if there wasn't already a non-default value set.

Comment: The reason it doesn’t is because the XAML parser usually interprets Something=“” as Something=null

Comment: The Xaml parser would not interpret `""` as `null` unless a type converter or value serializer were to intervene.  It certainly would not translate an empty string into null for a property with a `String` type (as is the case here), as the types match exactly.  My hasty and flawed analysis of `MenuItem.CoerceInputGestureText` was to blame.

Comment: Ah, didn’t realize it was a string property, for most properties (which the vast majority of UI properties are not strings), empty string gets turned into null, but of course you are correct in this case

Comment: The Xaml parser never 'interprets' an empty string as `null`.  It's true that assigning some properties to empty strings _may result_ a null assignment, but that is not a decision of the parser; it is a decision of a type converter or value serializer (which the parser consults when  source and target types don't match).  For example, setting `Command=""` produces `null` because `CommandConverter.ConverFrom` returns `null` when a conversion fails, and **not** because the Xaml parser somehow equates `""` to `null`.  Using an empty string in Xaml when you really mean `{x:Null}` is a code smell.

Comment: FYI, if you think you'd enjoy learning the nuances of how the Xaml parser works, I recommend reading the Xaml Language Spec.  It's quite interesting, and it's useful knowledge to have.  I covered [a little bit of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528909/how-is-xaml-interpreted-and-executed-at-runtime/20529118#20529118) on SO a few years ago.

Comment: So you would consider the type converters that actually make the xaml parser work not part of the “xaml parser” so that you can be technically correct? That is silly, you are just trying to win an argument on semantics.

Comment: It is not semantics.  You can specify what type converter or value serializer to use on a per-type or per-property basis.  The conversion behavior is pluggable, so suggesting that the parser makes the decision implies a reliable convention where none exists.  Many built-in WPF converters do not follow the convention you describe, like `BrushConverter`.

Comment: I already know all that, and I know plenty about how value converters and markup extensions work, I have written plenty of them myself over the years. By "xaml parser", I mean whatever *complete* set of tools that turns raw xml strings into C#. It realize that the "xaml parser proper" is extensible, but at the end of the day all of it functions as one to accomplish something. I also make no implication of a "reliable convention" by use of the word "usually". Stop being so condescending.

Comment: Dave, I am sorry if I was condescending.  That was not my intention, and if i came off that way, please accept my apology.  I know I can be rather defensive (and daft!) at times.  I do get your point, so let me offer you a less pedantic rebuttal: of the 150 or so properties (direct and attached) that can be set on a UI element in WPF, I can only find 4 of them that will treat an empty string as `null` in Xaml: `SelectedItem`, `Cursor`, `ImageSource.Source`, and `Command`.